# Application crashes when sending notification on foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send a notification message with data payload on foreground, my application crashes. It **works** fine when it is **in background or killed state** but why it doesn't work on foreground?

This is the **error**:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at ... MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:57)

and the error **indicates** the line given in MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
if(dataType.equals(getString(R.string.direct_message))){
```

**Compiler** already catches the problem and it says:

> Method invocation 'equals' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

This is a small part of **Firebase Messaging Service** class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private static final int BROADCAST_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String notificationBody = "";
        String notificationTitle = "";
        String notificationData = "";
        try{
           notificationData = remoteMessage.getData().toString();
           notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
           notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
           Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: data: " + notificationData);
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: notification body: " + notificationBody);
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: notification title: " + notificationTitle);


        String dataType = remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.data_type));
        if(dataType.equals(getString(R.string.direct_message))){
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: new incoming message.");
            String title = remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.data_title));
            String message = remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.data_message));
            String messageId = remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.data_message_id));
            sendMessageNotification(title, message, messageId);

        }
    }
}
```

I guess `(getString(R.string.direct_message)` is null but I don't know why it is null on foreground. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `dataType` must be null, you could add a breakpoint to check it

Comment: whenever there is a crash - you should post the logs - in this case from logat - with log trace its much easy to see the class's method/code causing the crash

Comment: `if(dataType != null && dataType.equals(getString(R.string.direct_message))){`

Comment: I've checked the logs and `dataType` is null as you said and I also updated if statement as you write @Frank. However, if I do this, app doesn't crash but it doesn't get the notification either. My aim is it getting notification on foreground too. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)